# Merge conflict marker encountered

Tags: git

**SourceTree Merge Conflict**

I have created a local **"Test"** branch in *SourceTree* for testing some new features and everything seemed to work fine. Then I merged the **"master"** branch into my local **"Test"** branch and unfortunately, pushed it. But since then by running **"ng serve"** I'm getting the following error:

```
52 <<<<<<< HEAD
app/app.module.ts:54:1 - error TS1185: Merge conflict marker encountered.

54 =======
app/app.module.ts:56:1 - error TS1185: Merge conflict marker encountered.

56 >>>>>>> master
app/example/example.module.ts:9:1 - error TS1185: Merge conflict marker encountered.

9 <<<<<<< HEAD
```

I have no idea what's going on here. Is there any way to solve this issue easily?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

while you're merging master into your local feature branch there are some conflicts, you need to resolve them by accepting the current or incoming changes. Open those files and remove these `<<<<<<< HEAD` `>>>>>>> master` and commit your changes. If you've `Visual Studio Code` will clearly show you the conflicts.

**Files that had conflict marker:**

```
app/example/example.module.ts:9:1 // in this file line number 9 should've conflict marker **>>>>>**
app/app.module.ts:54:1 // in this file line number 54 should've conflict marker **>>>>>**
app/app.module.ts:56:1 // in this file line number 56 should've conflict marker **>>>>>**
```

> Once you resolved the conflicts and still getting the error, the files
> might have been cached, try to switching to another branch, then
> switching back to the original.

> Still Webpack isn't noticing your file changes - https://dev.to/pnevares/webpack-isn-t-noticing-your-file-changes-did-you-do-something-wrong-34dc

Comment: This answer is alright for those actually having conflicts. As you can see from most comments, we have actually already resolved the conflicts, but the files have been cached, so we still get the error.

Answer (score 123):

For anyone coming from Google, I had a similar issue in React, but I was 100% confident that I had already resolved all conflicts.

I fixed it by **switching to another branch, then switching back to the original**.

---

If this still does not fix the issue, [remove the Node Modules cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67689860/10226703) with `rm -Rf node_modules/.cache`

Comment: Craziest problem solution I've ever lived through. I've seen it all now. This actually worked for me.

Comment: Probably some sort of caching is going on. For me similar to this solution purging the repo and starting over resolved this.

Comment: I keep running into the problem, and this is not solving it for me. Every time I have React running locally and then have to merge I get this problem. I have tried cache clean a few times to no success. Looks like I may have to reinstall with npm install.

Comment: I tried the branch switch change and it did not work for me. What did work was renaming the offending file. This then caused compile to fail. I then renamed the file back and it compiled.

Comment: Worked!! thks folk

Answer (score 56):

For those coming from Google that:

- had the error with React
- are 100% confident they have already resolved all conflict
- [user-124812948 's answer did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037433/10613336)

I fixed it by deleting node_modules cache: `rm -Rf node_modules/.cache`

Here is the link to [an article that explains what's happening](https://dev.to/pnevares/webpack-isn-t-noticing-your-file-changes-did-you-do-something-wrong-34dc)

Comment: This worked! The solution with switching branches did not work for me!

Comment: I tried both of these and it didn't work. What did work for me was editing the file after clearing the node_modules cache

Comment: Thanks, @SofienM! BTW This actually should be an answer to the question...

Comment: THIS!!!!! Is the right answer. Switching branches didn't work for me and I obviously wasn't gonna wipe node_modules and start over lol.
FIY, if you have sub-repos like I do, don't forget to clean the cache of both the top-level node_modules and the subrepo node_modules.
Finally, you'll need to make a change to the file in question as suggested in one of the answers below. Then the build error goes away at last.

Comment: FYI, `rm -rf` same as `rm -Rf`

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules/.cache` wasn't enough. Then changing branches and back also wasn't enough. Then editing a file also wasn't enough. Finally after completing quitting VSC multiple times, the error resolved.

Answer (score 6):

Encountered this issue in React, and I am sure that the merge conflicts are resolved.

I fixed it by editing the file content, by simply add/remove some code, wait it compile and reload again.

Comment: That actually worked

Comment: This worked for me too, but only after cleaning the cache as suggested above.

Comment: Wow can't believe this was the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can try to stop and run the npm as a short solution. Worked for me.

Comment: this worked for me like magic

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, but with a Vue.js project. Suggested solutions did not work for me. I had to remove and re-install all the dependencies. Only after `rm -rf node_modules && yarn install` the error goes away!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pulled lastest code from the master branch before merging Master into Test.

Answer (score 0):

If the conflict markers are in an auto-generated file, regenerate it.

Answer (score 0):

If tsconfig.json still has conflicts, the above error will appear in every source file.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me, but rebuilding my docker containers

```
docker-compose down -v && yarn install && docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d
```

fixed it